# Magento adminhtml template file not loading

Tags: xml, magento

I have set correct config.xml controller and layout file. but the template "sendfeedbackmail.phtml" is not loading. I guess I am missing something here. Also please suggest a correct procedure to build admin page inside a custom module, I have followed a tutorial and got the controller stuff to work. It routes to the correct controller. but when the loadLayout() happens, the file is not calling the correct template though I have specified it in the layout/ordermanagement.xml

I have my controller as

```
class MagicCrate_OrderManagement_Adminhtml_OrdermanagementbackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
       $this->loadLayout();
       $this->_title($this->__("Cron Panel"));
       $this->renderLayout();
    }


    public function feedbackAction($value='')
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_title($this->__("Feedback Mail Panel"));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

I have my layout/ordermanagement.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <ordermanagement_adminhtml_ordermanagementbackend_index>
       <reference name="content">
            <block type="ordermanagement/adminhtml_ordermanagementbackend" name="ordermanagementbackend" template="ordermanagement/ordermanagementbackend.phtml"/>
       </reference>
  </ordermanagement_adminhtml_ordermanagementbackend_index>
  <ordermanagement_adminhtml_ordermanagementbackend_feedback>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="ordermanagement/adminhtml_ordermanagementbackend" name="sendfeedbackmail" template="ordermanagement/sendfeedbackmail.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
       </reference>
  </ordermanagement_adminhtml_ordermanagementbackend_feedback>
</layout>
```

ordermanagement/sendfeedbackmail.phtml as

```
<h2>Hey works</h2>
```

The ultimate aim is, if I invoke feedbackAction, I should get Hey works in the admin content block.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Debug :

1) add echo 'something';exit; inside your feedbackAction and check if controller is working properly. If not, check file permissions of controllers and your confix.xml declaration of routers.

2) Check the layout file, check the block types you have mentioned for the 2 phtmls. Make sure the blocks are present. Also check file permissions of blocks and phtmls.

3) If not, last but not the least, Try removing $value="" parameter from the controller action and check.

This should work. :)

Comment: tested all the three.. The controller works fine. echo works fine. The blocks in layout are present but they are empty! It should work even if the blocks are empty. the third one, $value is just some parameter, so I guess it should have no impact in this.

Comment: Did you check file permissions for phtmls and layouts?

Comment: Please remove  output="toHtml" from your layout.xml and try ! Everything else looks perfect. Also make sure your block extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template

Comment: Also check if you have added entry in config.xml, inside <adminhtml><menu> node to display your phtml content in backend menu tab